# What is an ObjectMother?

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns

What is an ObjectMother and what are common usage scenarios for this pattern?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> ObjectMother starts with the factory pattern, by delivering prefabricated test-ready objects via a simple method call. It moves beyond the realm of the factory by 
>   facilitating the customization of created objects, 
>   providing methods to update the objects during the tests, and 
>   if necessary, deleting the object from the database at the completion of the test.
>
> Some reasons to use ObjectMother:
>   * Reduce code duplication in tests, increasing test maintainability
>   * Make test objects super-easily accessible, encouraging developers to write more tests.
>   * Every test runs with fresh data.
>   * Tests always clean up after themselves.

(http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObjectMother)

Comment: I'm just wondering, is there an alternate (better) name for 'Object Mother' ?  Perhaps 'TestDataProvider', or something like that?

Comment: * Every test runs with fresh data. IMHO, that is something you may want to avoid. I believe unit tests should be deterministic tests.

Comment: @Gabriel I think "fresh" here means "untouched by other tests" rather than "randomly regenerated", so it could still be deterministically-created.

Answer (score 16):

See "[Test Data Builders: an alternative to the Object Mother pattern](http://www.natpryce.com/articles/000714.html)" for an argument of why to use a Test Data Builder instead of an Object Mother.  It explains what both are.

Comment: That article is now hosted at www.natpryce.com.

Comment: It is funny because I have arrived to this post searching about “ObjectMother pattern as an alternative to Test Data Builder”.

Comment: Object mother pattern can just return Builder and you just kill two birds with one stone - you have customisable objects (thanks to builder) and predefined objects (builder with some fields already filled) at once.

Answer (score 4):

As stated elsewhere, ObjectMother is a Factory for generating Objects typically **(exclusively?)** for use in Unit Tests.

Where they are of great use is for generating complex objects where the data is of no particular significance to the test.

Where you might have created an empty instance below such as

```
    Order rubishOrder = new Order("NoPropertiesSet");
    _orderProcessor.Process(rubishOrder);
```

you would use a sensible one from the ObjectMother

```
    Order motherOrder = ObjectMother.SimpleOrder();
    _orderProcessor.Process(motherOrder);
```

This tends to help with situations where the class being tested starts to rely on a sensible object being passed in.

For instance if you added some OrderNumber validation to the Order class above, you would simply need to instantiate the OrderNumber on the SimpleObject class in order for all the existing tests to pass, leaving you to concentrate on writing the validation tests.

If you had just instantiated the object in the test you would need to add it to every test (it is shocking how often I have seen people do this).

Of course, this could just be extracted out to a method, but putting it in a separate class allows it to be shared between multiple test classes.

Another recommended behavior is to use good descriptive names for your methods, to promote reuse.  It is all too easy to end up with one object per test, which is definitely to be avoided.  It is better to generate objects that represent general rather than specific attributes and then customize for your test.  For instance `ObjectMother.WealthyCustomer()` rather than `ObjectMother.CustomerWith1MdollarsSharesInBigPharmaAndDrivesAPorsche()` and `ObjectMother.CustomerWith1MdollarsSharesInBigPharmaAndDrivesAPorscheAndAFerrari()`